# How to import data into a varray using sqlldr

Tags: oracle, loader, sql-loader, varray

I am trying to import data into Oracle database using sqlldr.

I am using this documentation, but not successfully: [sqlldr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch10.htm#1008188) and [sqlldr2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10825/ldr_loading.htm#i1007180)

Decribing what I am doing:

create the varray type and the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE fv_integer_varray_12 AS VARRAY(12) OF INTEGER NOT NULL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VC_Array_MInteger_12 AS Object (
  fv_array fv_integer_varray_12,
  MEMBER FUNCTION   typeDimension   RETURN NUMBER ,
  MEMBER FUNCTION typeName RETURN VARCHAR2);
/  

CREATE TABLE fv_varray_12 (
id NUMBER, 
fv fv_integer_varray_12,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Create the control file:

```
options (errors=9999999, rows=5)
load data
 characterset WE8MSWIN1252
 infile '<path>'
 badfile '<path>'
 discardfile '<path>'
 into table fv_varray_12
 fields terminated by " "
( id, fv VARRAY COUNT(12) (fv))
```

The data to be load is:

```
8 18 29 38 9 16 15 14 16 18 16 13 15 
9 22 31 32 8 13 18 10 15 18 16 13 13
```

When I try to load it through the command:

```
sqlldr user/pass control=imp_fv_12dim.ctl
```

I get the error:

> SQL*Loader-403: Referenced column  not present in table FV_VARRAY_12.

But it is not true as both the id and fv columns are there.

There must be something wrong in my control file. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the keyword `CONSTANT`:

```
fv VARRAY COUNT(CONSTANT 12) (fv)
```

That is missing from the example in the documentation (but then their data also look odd); but it is shown as required [in the *count_spec* syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-4BD87035-FE6D-4735-86A4-31C844ACC59A.htm), which is linked to from [the 12c documentaion](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-B769A8EC-48F4-4E8E-8896-2D7A5463112C.htm) on loading VARRAYs - but is also available in earlier versions of the documentation too..

With your sample data and just that modification to the control file:

```
options (errors=9999999, rows=5)
load data
characterset WE8MSWIN1252
infile 'imp_fv_12dim.dat'
badfile 'imp_fv_12dim.bad'
discardfile 'imp_fv_12dim.dis'
into table fv_varray_12
fields terminated by " "
( id,
  fv VARRAY COUNT(CONSTANT 12) (fv)
)
```

then it works:

```
> sqlldr user/pass control=imp_fv_12dim.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Mon Dec 4 17:41:04 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2
```

And querying shows the data:

```
column fv format a80
select * from fv_varray_12;

        ID FV                                                                              
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         8 FV_INTEGER_VARRAY_12(18, 29, 38, 9, 16, 15, 14, 16, 18, 16, 13, 15)             
         9 FV_INTEGER_VARRAY_12(22, 31, 32, 8, 13, 18, 10, 15, 18, 16, 13, 13)
```